# Change color of a bar in google columnchart

Tags: google-visualization

I am using columnchart to generate a chart . Below is the code:

```
function drawActiveJobsChart() {
    var i=0;
    var j=0;

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string','Systems');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Counts');

    $.getJSON('SubSystemNumbers.action', function(json) {

        $.each( json.SysActNum, function( key, val ) {
            i++;
        });
        data.addRows(i);
        $.each( json.SysActNum, function( key, val ) {


            if (val>=30) {

            data.setProperty(j,1,'style','color:red');

            }
            data.setValue(j, 0,key);
            data.setValue(j, 1,val);
            j++;

          });
    });


    var options = {
      title: 'System Numbers',
      width:900, height:400,
      allowHtml: true,
      hAxis: {title: 'Systems', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'},textStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(chartDiv));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Now i have added logic to change the bar color to red when return val is greater than 30 . I tried running in debug and code is executing fine but bar is not showing in red . Please suggest ! Help is appreciated

Comment: Update your post with some example JSON from your `getJSON` AJAX query, and I'll test this to see what might be causing the problem.

Comment: My JSON is simply returning system name and value and every thing is working fine columnchart is populating fine . Its just the bar with value greater or equal to 30 is not showing in red

Comment: I see your problem now, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the "style" property of a cell is not going to change the color of a bar, you need to add a "style" role column to your DataTable:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string','Systems');
data.addColumn('number', 'Counts');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
```

and add the style information to this column:

```
$.getJSON('SubSystemNumbers.action', function(json) {
    $.each( json.SysActNum, function( key, val ) {
        var style = (val >= 30) ? 'color: red' : null;
        data.addRow([key, val, style]);
    });
});
```

see working example based on your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/dGYs7/

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody else runs in to the same issue as me:

I had a similar problem where I couldn't change the color of specific bars in a bar-chart. I  did as the documentation said, and tried the answer here by asgallant, but nothing worked.

Turned out, I just needed to change `google.charts.Bar` to `google.visualization.ColumnChart`.